# Dump foreign images using Nutch

Tags: web-crawler, nutch

I'm trying to dump full site content using Apache Nutch. It's working fine for html pages and images from same domain, but it doesn't dump images from another sites, e.g. if I have a site with domain `foo.bar` with content:

```html
<html>
<body>
  <img src="http://foo.bar/img"/>
  <img src="http://another.domain/img"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Nutch will dump only first image (`foo.bar/img`) but not second (`another.domain/img`).

Right now I'm using almost default configuration. How to configure nutch to fetch foreign images from other domains?

**UPDATE:**
I'm running Nutch from Java code with 4 parsing cycles,
this is my Nutch code: https://gist.github.com/g4s8/2875790194b3482e31ee9e83561618e2

Comment: Can you share your config in a gist or similar? There are a number of different settings that could be preventing Nutch from following the external link. Are you running multiple crawl cycles? Would be helpful if you post the command that you're using to run Nutch.

Comment: @JorgeLuis this is a link to Nutch config files https://send.firefox.com/download/e44616848550df4b/#NMf_f3mdEWFjicuhK74B6g,  I'll update the question with more details (cycles, etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the config that you shared. I see that on the `nutch-site.xml` you have the following:

```
<property>
    <name>db.ignore.external.links</name>
    <value>true</value>
</property>
```

This is effectively ignoring all external links. On the `db-ignore-external-exemptions.txt` file you have configured some exemptions:

```
+(?i)\.(jpg|png|gif)$
```

But in order of these settings to work, you need to enable the `urlfilter-ignoreexempt` plugin. You can see how [here](https://github.com/apache/nutch/blob/master/src/plugin/urlfilter-ignoreexempt/README.md).

With this combination, you can just ignore all external links and just add to your CrawlDB those that match the rules on the exemption files (images in your case).

Since you're running Nutch within a Java process my advise is to have a standalone local Nutch setup where you can test your configuration. `bin/nutch parsechecker`,  `bin/nutch indexchecker` and `bin/nutch plugin` are very helpful for debugging. You can test (using these commands) some configurations with specific test cases without needing to launch an entire crawl (saves a lot of time).